# No package stress available. How to install stress on CentOS 7.2?

Tags: software-installation

I'm running virtual machine CentOS 7.2 on Azure and want to install stress tool for some test related to Alert.
The point is even though i installed latest repository 7.6, i still wasn't be able to install stress.

```
[root@azure-virtualmachine ~]# yum install epel-release
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, langpacks
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * epel: ftp.iij.ad.jp
Package epel-release-7-6.noarch already installed and latest version
Nothing to do

[root@azure-virtualmachine ~]# yum install stress
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, langpacks
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * epel: ftp.riken.jp
No package stress available.
```

Someone tell me how to fix this please?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Stress is not available (yet) in Epel-Repository for RHEL 7. Google will find a RPM you can download from: ftp://fr2.rpmfind.net/linux/dag/redhat/el7/en/x86_64/dag/RPMS/stress-1.0.2-1.el7.rf.x86_64.rpm and install with `yum localinstall stress-1.0.2-1.el7.rf.x86_64.rpm`.

Comment: I think that "localinstall" option is not necessary anymore in CentOS 7.

Comment: epel have a package named stress

Answer (score 15):

[`stress` is now packaged in the EPEL 7 repository](https://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/7/x86_64/s/) so this should be the preferred way of installation. To enable this repo, you should follow the instructions from [the Fedora Wiki](https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/EPEL#How_can_I_use_these_extra_packages.3F) and install the `epel-release` package. Once enabled, you can then install `stress`. For example:

```
sudo yum install -y epel-release
sudo yum install -y stress
```